# How do pocket calculators simplify fractions and keep imprecise numbers as fractions?

Tags: algorithm, math, fractions, arbitrary-precision

Could someone explain how calculators (such as casio pocket ones) manage equations such as '500/12' and are able to return '125/3' as the result, alternately can someone name some algorithms which do this?

By imprecise numbers I mean numbers which cannot be represented in a fixed number of decimal places, such as 0.333 recurring.

Windows calculator is able to demonstrate this, if you perform '1/3' you will get '0.3333333333333333' as the answer, but then if you multiply this by 3 you will arrive back at '1'.

Comment: One does not simply.... keep imprecise numbers as fractions. <boromir.jpg>

Comment: Windows calculator isn't doing anything fancy - it's simply the case that the result is sufficiently close to 1 that it gets rounded to 1 in an IEEE floating point number.

Answer (score 1):

My HP's fraction display let's you set several modes for fraction display:

- Set a maximum denominator.  The displayed the fraction is `n/d` closest to the internal floating point value without *d* exceeding the maximum.  For example, if the maximum is set to 10, the floating point number for *pi* is nearest the fraction `22/7`.  However, if the maximum is 1000, then the nearest fraction is `355/113`.
- Set an exact denominator and reduce the result.  The displayed fraction is the `n/d` closest to the internal floating point value where *d* is equal to the exact denominator.  Having computed *n*, the fraction is then reduced by the greatest-common-denominator.  For example, if the denominator is fixed to be 32, then the floating point number 0.51 is nearest to `16/32` which gets reduced to `1/2`.  Likewise, the floating point number 0.516 is nearest to `17/32` which is irreducible.
- Set an exact denominator and do not reduce the result.  For example, 0.51 is shown as `16/32`, an unreduced fraction.

The algorithm for the maximum-denominator approach uses [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction).  An easy to follow example in Python can be found in the limit_denominator method at http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py#l206 .

The method for the exact-denominator approach is easier.  Given a denominator *d* and a floating point number *x*, the numerator is just `d * x` rounded to the nearest integer.  Then reduce the fraction `n/d` by computing the [greatest common divisor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)

Optionally, the original floating point number can be replaced by the displayed fraction.  This is known as a snap-to-grid.  That way, you can enter 0.333 to create a fraction that is *exactly* equal to `1/3`.  This lets you do exact fractional arithmetic without round-off.

Hope this answer clears everything up for you :-)  Let me know if any part needs elaboration or further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at the GMP library's [rational number functions](http://gmplib.org/manual/Rational-Number-Functions.html#Rational-Number-Functions). At some point, you will need to accept finite precision in your calculations, unless the sequence of operations is particularly simple. The irrationals (transcendental functions / constants) can only be approximated, e.g., as continued fractions.